# Changing BackgroundColor for DeadPixel Test

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this code

```
function myFunction() {
                var bg = document.bgColor;
                if (bg = "black") {
                    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                } else if (bg = "white") {
                    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                } else if (bg = "red") {
                    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                } else if (bg = "green") {
                    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                }
```

but it doesn't change the backgroundColor, what's the problem?

P.S: I'm new at the coding, sorry for your eyes :/

EDIT:

I changed my code with this(Thank you @Weary Adventurer)

```
var colors = ["black", "white", "red", "green", "blue"];
var color = 0;    

function change_color(){
    var e = document.getElementById("myDIV");

    if(color >= (colors.length - 1)) color = 0;
    else color++;

    e.style.background = colors[color];
}

var timer = setTimeout(change_color, 1000);
```

But I wanna send people another page after bg turned blue, Does `window.location.replace("...");` helps?

Comment: Are you calling the function? Like whats the trigger?

Comment: `console.log(bg);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To check if something is equal to something else, use the operator `==`.
- I defined a variable `e` (for **e**lement) so there's less repetitions.
- If there's only one "action" to do in an *if, else, while* or *for* block you can get rid of curly braces and write it in one line for visual clarity.

Here's your fixed code.

```
function myFunction() {
    var bg = document.bgColor;
    var e = document.getElementById("myDIV");

    if (bg == "black") e.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    else if (bg == "white") e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    else if (bg == "red") e.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    else if (bg == "green") e.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

You said you are making a dead pixel test. You can define colors to loop through with an array:

```
var colors = ["black", "white", "red", "green", "blue"];
```

You can set a timeout or wait before executing code by using `setTimeout(callback, ms)` function.
You can set a variable to function or pass a function as a parameter for another function in Javascript. So, if you wish to change those colors every X milliseconds, use this:

```
var colors = ["black", "white", "red", "green", "blue"];
var color = 0;    

function change_color(){
    var e = document.getElementById("myDIV");

    if(color >= (colors.length - 1)) color = 0;
    else color++;

    e.style.background = colors[color];
}

var timer = setTimeout(change_color, 1000);
```

`colors` is an array of strings, `color` is an index of a current color. So, by doing `colors[color]` when `color` is `0`, you will access 1st element of an array (because arrays start from 0) which is `"black"` (note the quotes).

Function `change_color` sets the background color of an element to the next one from array. It also makes sure the index pointer `color` does not go out of the array.

Comment: Even with those typos fixed, I doubt it will still work.

Comment: @epascarello Why?

Comment: Most browsers do not bring back named colors.

Comment: @epascarello You mean don't support color aliases? Pretty sure all of them do have some kind of support for basic colors such as "white", "black", etc.

Comment: By the way, can i send people to another page? I mean after background turned to blue.

Comment: @Suppy yes, you can.
In `color >= (colors.length - 1)` check instead of setting the color to 0 use window.location.replace or whatever, and make sure the timer is stopped

Answer (score 0):

First step:
Are you importing the jquery library into your code?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if yes:
are you calling this function on your code?

I ran your page calling the function `myFunction();` on js code and it been sucessfull fully for me. Say me if this work for you

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that a tag with `id="myDIV"` exists (in a case-sensitive manner), make sure that the tag is visible. When you are sure the tag is correctly displayed, make sure you call `myFunction();` maybe in this manner:

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 30000); //It will run twice/minute
```

EDIT:

Also, you have syntax errors in your `function`, where you are using the assignment operator of `=` instead of the equals operator of `===` in your `if` and `else` conditions.

Comment: The problem is clearly in the if condition: `if (bg = "black")` should be `if (bg == "black")`

Comment: @WearyAdventurer, thank you for pointing that out, did not observe it.